# can not get response return from node api into angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I wrote a file upload snippet with multer in nodejs. It is working and files have been successfully uploaded to the server and **I got the response**(tested using postman),But when I call that API from client side(angular),I'm **NOT** getting the returned response from node.but file was uploaded. I'm using promise to handle responses.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const upload = require('../startup/config');

router.post('/', upload.single('invoice'), (req, res) => {
  return res.status(201).send({ status: 'success'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

client side

```
async onUpload() {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('invoice', this.selectedInvoice, this.selectedInvoice.name);

    const result = await this.orderService.uploadInvoice(uploadData);
    console.log('result', result); // <= not execute this line
}
```

order service

```
uploadInvoice(formData) {
    return this.http.post('/api/invoices', formData).toPromise();
}
```

I need to run the line mentioned here, Did i miss something here? Need your help.
Thanks!

Comment: *not execute this line* means that you are getting nothing in the console and there is no error also.

Comment: Open the Network Tab on the Browser's Dev Tools and check the response that you're getting. The code looks fine to me. You using `Http` or `HttpClient` to make the AJAX call?